# Spring Webclient multipart/form-data request

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-webflux, pre-signed-url, spring-webclient

I am new to Java (Spring Boot), and i am trying to send a `multipart/form-data` POST request to s3 to upload a file.

I managed to do this using spring's `RestTemplate` like this :

```
    public String uploadFile(byte[] file, Map<String, Object> fields, String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
            formData.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        formData.add("file", file);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, headers);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(new URI(url), request, String.class);
        return response;
    }
```

Then i tried to do the same using `webclient`, but i can not and AWS respond with `The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.`

Here is the code using webclient :

```
    public String uploadFileWebc(byte[] file, Map<String, Object> fields, String url) {

        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
            builder.part(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        }

        builder.part("file", file).filename("file");
        MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> parts = builder.build();


        Void result = webClient.filter(errorHandlingFilter()).build().post().uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .contentLength(file.length)
                .bodyValue(parts)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .block();
        return "Done Uploading.";
    }
```

Can  anybody please point out what am i missing ?

Comment: Might not be the problem, but your passing an empty MultiValueMap to the `bodyValue` method instead of your multi part body, that's most likely where your problem was.... Also, you shouldn't set the content length yourself, Web clients / rest templates will add it automatically and the formula isn't as simple as the `file.length` you put, since you have other parameters in that map, and the `file` entry itself is a parameter meaning it has an additional header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `webclient` does not add the `content-length` header due to its streaming nature, and S3 API needs this header to be sent.

I ended up using `restTemplate` for uploading files to S3.

Comment: Can you please share webclient object u are using exists in which package?